# Update list value in list of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, lambda

I have a list of dictionaries (much like in JSON). I want to apply a function to a key in every dictionary of the list.

```
>> d = [{'a': 2, 'b': 2}, {'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'a': 1, 'b': 2}]

# Desired value
[{'a': 200, 'b': 2}, {'a': 100, 'b': 2}, {'a': 100, 'b': 2}, {'a': 100, 'b': 2}]

# If I do this, I can only get the changed key
>> map(lambda x: {k: v * 100 for k, v in x.iteritems() if k == 'a'}, d)
[{'a': 200}, {'a': 100}, {'a': 100}, {'a': 100}]

# I try to add the non-modified key-values but get an error
>> map(lambda x: {k: v * 100 for k, v in x.iteritems() if k == 'a' else k:v}, d)

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
File "<stdin>", line 1
map(lambda x: {k: v * 100 for k, v in x.iteritems() if k == 'a' else k:v}, d)
```

How can I achieve this?

EDIT: 'a' and 'b' are not the only keys. These were selected for demo purposes only.

Comment: Are we to assume that `a` will always be in these dictionaries, if not, what is expected?

Comment: Yes, the keys will be the same across the dictionaries.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Iterate through the list and update the desired dict item,

```
lst = [{'a': 2, 'b': 2}, {'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'a': 1, 'b': 2}]

for d in lst:
    d['a'] *= 100
```

Using list comprehension will give you speed but it will create a **new list and n new dicts**, It's useful if you don't wanna mutate your list, here it is

```
new_lst = [{**d, 'a': d['a']*100} for d in lst]
```

In **python 2.X** we can't use `{**d}` so I built `custom_update` based on the `update` method and the code will be

```
def custom_update(d):
    new_dict = dict(d)
    new_dict.update({'a':d['a']*100})
    return new_dict

[custom_update(d) for d in lst]
```

If for every item in the list you want to update a different key

```
keys = ['a', 'b', 'a', 'b'] # keys[0] correspond to lst[0] and keys[0] correspond to lst[0], ...

for index, d in enumerate(lst):
    key = keys[index]
    d[key] *= 100
```

using list comprehension

```
[{**d, keys[index]: d[keys[index]] * 100} for index, d in enumerate(lst)]
```

In **python 2.x** the list comprehension will be

```
def custom_update(d, key):
    new_dict = dict(d)
    new_dict.update({key: d[key]*100})
    return new_dict

[custom_update(d, keys[index]) for index, d in enumerate(lst)]
```

Comment: @drum {**d} will not work in python2, I updated the answer and I added a python 2.x compatible code

Answer (score 5):

You can use your inline conditionals (ternaries) in a better location within a comprehension:

```
>>> d = [{'a': 2, 'b': 2}, {'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'a': 1, 'b': 2}]
>>> d2 = [{k: v * 100 if k == 'a' else v for k, v in i.items()} for i in d]
>>> d2
[{'a': 200, 'b': 2}, {'a': 100, 'b': 2}, {'a': 100, 'b': 2}, {'a': 100, 'b': 2}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `map()` call is close to working, you just need to change the order of your dict comprehension, and turn `else k:v` into `else v`:

```
>>> d = [{'a': 2, 'b': 2}, {'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'a': 1, 'b': 2}]
>>> list(map(lambda x: {k: v * 100 if k == 'a' else v for k, v in x.items()}, d))
[{'a': 200, 'b': 2}, {'a': 100, 'b': 2}, {'a': 100, 'b': 2}, {'a': 100, 'b': 2}]
```

Answer (score 0):

After your edit of "`'a'` and `'b'` are not the only keys. These were selected for demo purposes only", **here is a very simple `map` function that alters only the value of `'a'`, and leaves the rest as is**:

```
map(lambda x: x.update({'a': x['a']*100}), d)
```

---

My original answer was:

I think the simplest and most appropriate way of this is iterating in `d` and utilizing the fact that each item in `d` is a dictionary that has keys `'a'` and `'b'`:

```
res = [{'a':e['a']*100, 'b':e['b']} for e in d]
```

Result:

```
[{'a': 200, 'b': 2}, {'a': 100, 'b': 2}, {'a': 100, 'b': 2}, {'a': 100, 'b': 2}]
```

Comment: With your update, the map will return a list/iterator while updating the existing list. Although neat, I wouldn't say is very clean.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a function, you may want to provide a target key and corresponding value:

```
d = [{'a': 2, 'b': 2}, {'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'a': 1, 'b': 2}]
f = lambda new_val, d1, key='a': {a:b*new_val if a == key else b for a, b in d1.items()}
new_d = list(map(lambda x:f(100, x), d))
```

Output:

```
[{'a': 200, 'b': 2}, {'a': 100, 'b': 2}, {'a': 100, 'b': 2}, {'a': 100, 'b': 2}]
```